# Which is the better way to define Model's Method in Laravel?

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel, laravel-4

I have been using Laravel for about 2 months. And I'm just wondered about how to define models in the proper way.

For example, I define model's method in this way.

```
public static get_book_static($id){
   return Book::where($id)->first();
}

public get_book($id){
   return Book::where($id)->first();
}
```

In models, I defined the methods both in static and not.

I want to know that which one is the better way to use, because Laravel seems to use a lot of static methods out there.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful this is to you but Laravel's 'static' methods are actually facades to give some syntactic sugar and not simple static method calls - this video explains it very well https://tutsplus.com/lesson/when-they-say-laravel-shouldnt-use-static-methods/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a better way. Static is necessary in some cases and in some cases it is not. If you need to call a method statically with instantiating a model object first, then it needs to be static. For example, in your controller:

```
$myBook = Book::find($id); // find() is built into Laravel's ORM

$myBook->doSomething(); // doSomething() is a custom non-static function that you added to your Book model.

$anotherBook = Book::findSomeOtherType(); // findSomeOtherType() is a custom static function you added to the Book model.
```

Also, it looks like you are doing extra, unnecessary work. The `Book` object IS your model:

```
Book::where($id)->first();
```

is the same as

```
Book::find($id);
```

You shouldn't have to create any sort of `public get_book($id)` function. Just use `Book::find($id)` directly in your controller.

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

Comment: I'm wondered that -- does Laravel has models autoloader?. Or I have to initiate it myself (in controller)

Comment: Models are autoloaded when you use them. Laravel takes care of all of it for you.